Inequality in probability (maximum)
Let $(X_n)$ be a nonnegative sequence of random variables.
We define $S_n := \sum_{k=0}^{n} X_k + \sum_{k=n+1}^{N}\mathbb{E}[X_k]$. Let $\lambda>0$.
Do we have
$$
\lambda \mathbb{P}[\max_{n\leqslant N} S_n > \lambda] \leqslant \mathbb{E}[S_N] ?
$$

Is $\sum_{k=0}^{n} X_k$ deliberate with $n+1$ terms?    $\sum_{k=1}^{n} X_k$ seems more natural (if desired interpreting it as the empty sum $0$ when $n=0$)
